# Python EOL error in Exec function which evaluates to include a string containing a quote

Tags: python, string, escaping, exec

I am composing a string to execute to assign a value to an arbitrarily deep point in a json file, the values I'm assigning are strings and some of these strings contain quotes, this is where I get errors.

I've tried replacing the " in the strings I am assigning with ", encasing the string I'm assigning in triple quotes and both together.

Also everything below didn't start in triple quotes this is just a latest attempt to solve this.

**Code**

```
for index, row in md_csv.iterrows():
    json_ref_string = ''
    for k in row['Path']:
        json_ref_string += "['"
        json_ref_string += k
        json_ref_string +="']"
    my_string ="""jo"""+json_ref_string+"""="""+"""\""""+str(translated_csv.iloc[index][1])+"""\""""
    exec(my_string)
```

**Error**

```
    File "/Users/maxgreen/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-244-a1adf20fc0ec>", line 9, in <module>
    exec(my_string)

  File "<string>", line 1
    jo['agreementinfo']="Estoy celebrando este acuerdo en nombre de la parte contratante cuyos detalles he presentado en la página "INFORMACIÓN COMERCIAL", en adelante, el "COMERCIANTE""
                                                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: python_object = eval(my_string)?

Comment: Try adding `print(my_string)` to see what you're trying to execute.

Comment: It would probably be easier if you used a raw f-string.

Answer (score 1):

Advice from barmar in comments worked using string literals